# Insert report into ReportServer via TSQL

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, reportserver

As far as i understand SSRS are just databases "ReportServer & ReportServerTempDB"

So Is it possible to insert a report into the ReportServer.Catalog using a insert query. (note that the Content image is shortened for demonstration purposes)

```
INSERT [dbo].[Catalog] 
([ItemID], [Path], [Name], [ParentID], [Type], [Content], [Property], [CreatedByID], [CreationDate], 
[ModifiedByID], [ModifiedDate], [Parameter], [PolicyID],PolicyRoot,ExecutionFlag) 
VALUES 
(N'7dd2ae9e-063d-421c-a596-1995f97caea5', N'/LsnReports/Monitoring/tst001', N'tst001', 
N'db29a5c2-9738-4143-ad90-392aa6f26aa3', 2, 
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
N'<Properties>
  <Language>en-US</Language>
  <HasUserProfileQueryDependencies>False</HasUserProfileQueryDependencies>
  <HasUserProfileReportDependencies>False</HasUserProfileReportDependencies>
  <PageHeight>297.000007629395</PageHeight>
  <PageWidth>210</PageWidth>
  <TopMargin>20</TopMargin>
  <BottomMargin>20</BottomMargin>
  <LeftMargin>20</LeftMargin>
  <RightMargin>20</RightMargin>
</Properties>', 
N'e3ce88b0-16a2-4111-abf9-96d6866f513a', 
CAST(0x0000A55A0069B25C AS DateTime), 
N'e3ce88b0-16a2-4111-abf9-96d6866f513a', 
CAST(0x0000A55A0069B25C AS DateTime), 
N'<Parameters>
  <UserProfileState>0</UserProfileState>
</Parameters>', 
N'be91f173-be6a-48b7-940a-0ed79476b6c1',0,1)
```

I did try a simple report without datasources and datasets, but i get the following error in Report Manager.

"An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError) Get Online Help For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors"

I need to create an update to SSRS for just over 50 individual sites... Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deploy or change something on a group of servers you should script it using the [rs.exe utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152874.aspx) provided with Reporting Services. This utility allows you to administer a Report Server (including uploading content) using "rss" scripts written in Visual Basic that interact with the SSRS API.

Microsoft provide a [very comprehensive example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/dn531017.aspx) which is probably overkill for your needs but there are plenty of other rss examples available on the web.

I would not recommend trying to upload content (or any other SSRS change) by directly modifying the ReportServer database, you could easily end up with a report server in a non-functioning state.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, I'll have to go that route then.